# Литература по C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
Необходимо быстро освоить C#, ищется хорошая литература и ресурсы в целом. Необходимости объяснять, что такое  ООП, шаблоны проектирования, unit-тестирование, - нет (хорошо знаком с JAVA). Нужно быстро освоить особенности, современные возможности языка и стандартной библиотеки (интерес представляет как ms .net, так и mono). Кто с чего начинал, и кто с чего бы начал?
Спасибо.

Comment: Шилдт уже в процессе, знаю его по JAVA и CPP...

Comment: Andrew Troelsen 

> Use Google Luke

Comment: Ресурсы: MSDN - для общего развития, StackOverflow - для конкретных вопросов, CodeProject - для обзора интересных готовых решений.

Comment: мне почему-то больше всего понравились книги Рихтера и Албахари

Comment: Закройте в конце концов вопрос. Вам дали более чем достаточный список источников для обучения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Про mono](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Practical_Mono.html?id=YpIAry7MNCcC&redir_esc=y)

[Для того чтоб быстро освоить C#](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5642213/)

[ООП, Шаблоны](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5800704/)

[Классические книги по C#/.NET](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2011/04/cnet.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.knigka.info/2008/10/20/professional-c-2008.html

Answer (score 2):

Вот, на мой взгляд, самый лучший учебник по C# - [Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4(Эндрю Троелсен)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5602592/).

И для закрепления знаний - [C# 2010. Ускоренный курс для профессионалов (Трей Нэш)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5044374/).

Answer (score 1):

С этой книги лучше всего начать: [C# 4.0 полное руководство (Герберт Шилдт)](http://www.books.ru/books/c-40-polnoe-rukovodstvo-812748/?show=1). Этой книгой закрепить: [Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4.0 (Эндрю Троелсен)](http://www.books.ru/books/yazyk-programmirovaniya-c-2010-i-platforma-net-40-828814/?show=1), а этой улучшить полученные знания: [CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 на языке C# (Джеффри Рихтер)](http://www.books.ru/books/clr-via-c-programmirovanie-na-platforme-microsoft-net-framework-40-na-yazyke-c-1558886/?show=1).

Comment: отличный ответ, чтобы узнать названия книг, нужно перейти по трём ссылкам...дорвей какой-то